# Filling a numpy array with x random values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of size x, which I need to fill with 700 true.

For example:

```
a = np.zeros(5956)
```

If I want to fill this with 70 % True, I can write this:

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(a)) < 0.7
b = spam_df[msk]
```

But what if I need exactly 700 true, and the rest false?

Comment: You want to fill it with 700 elements that are true or you want to fill 70% of array values to True

Comment: I want to fill the array with exactly 700 true values that are randomly distributed in the array of 5956 values. Hence 800 true and 5956-800 false

Comment: Generate 700 random values (without replacement) from the 5956 range, and use those to set values of `a` to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
zeros = np.zeros(5956-700, dtype=bool)
ones=np.ones(700, dtype=bool)
arr=np.concatenate((ones,zeros), axis=0, out=None)
np.random.shuffle(arr)#Now, this array 'arr' is shuffled, with 700 Trues and rest False
```

Example - there should be 5 elements in an array with 3 True and rest False.

```
ones= np.ones(3, dtype=bool)   #array([True, True, True])
zeros= np.zeros(5-3, dtype=bool)   #array([False, False])
arr=np.concatenate((ones,zeros), axis=0, out=None)   #arr - array([ True,  True,  True, False, False])
np.random.shuffle(arr)    # now arr - array([False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: FYI: It would be bit more efficient to write `arr  = np.zeros(5956, dtype=bool); arr[:700] = 1` and then shuffle `arr`.

Comment: fair argument Warren :)

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np

x = 5956
a = np.zeros((x), dtype=bool)

random_places = np.random.choice(x, 700, replace=False)
a[random_places] = True
```